# Get height of the div after the state updates in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to get height of the div after the state is updated.

I have code as follows:

```
const FEATURES = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
const CHECKS = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3', 'check4', 'check5', 'check6', 'check7', 'check8', 'check9', 'check10']

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

      this.state = {
        checksView: false,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      let height = document.getElementById("view").clientHeight;
      console.log(height);
    }

    changeView(view, event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(view === "specs"){
            this.setState({checksView: false});
        }else{
            this.setState({checksView: true});
        }
    }

    renderContent(){
        if(this.state.checksView){
            return (
            <div id="view">
                {CHECKS.map(check => <div>{check}</div>)}
            </div>
          )
        }else{
            return (
            <div id="view">
                {FEATURES.map(check => <div>{check}</div>)}
            </div>
          )
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <div>
           <div>
             <div style={{float: "left", marginRight: 10}} onClick={this.changeView.bind(this, "specs")}>Specs</div>
             <div style={{float: "left"}} onClick={this.changeView.bind(this, "checks")}>Checks</div><br />
           </div>
           {this.renderContent()}     
        </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

In the `console.log` in `componentDidMount` I see the same value.
But the div with `checks` has bigger height than the div with features, but the content of the checks isn't loaded and I still get the height of the features div.

Any idea how can I wait to content to load after the state update and then check its height?

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/4038/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something after state change.

```
this.setState({checksView: false}, function() {
    //do something
});
```

more detail

```
getHeight() {
    let height = document.getElementById("view").clientHeight;
  console.log(height);
}

changeView(view, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(view === "specs"){
        this.setState({checksView: false}, function() {
            this.getHeight();
        });
    }else{
        this.setState({checksView: true}, function() {
            this.getHeight();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The content still isn't loaded. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you see the same value in `console` in `componentDidMount()` ? `componentDidMount()` just execute once after `Test` render.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't need to be in `componentDidMount` I just want to get the height of the div after the state is changed.